# How hide 'previous' and 'next' buttons on first and last slide in Bootstrap carouse

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a bootstrap carousel. The carousel moves one by one each item in order to display all the six items. My question is:

how to hide 'previous' and 'next' buttons on first and last slide?

Comment: Currently using url : https://codepen.io/ygoex/pen/meeaGw

Answer (score -1):

I'll put an ID on you're first and last item like this :

```
<div class="item" id="firstItem">
<div class="item" id="lastItem">
```

and on both of you're arrow image like this :

```
<a class="left carousel-control" id="leftArrow" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
<a class="right carousel-control" id="rightArrow" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
```

And then check in you're JS code if you're current item ID is firstItem or lastItem and hide you're both arrow.